# TypeScript: How to get a subclass's method to return parent this

Tags: class, typescript, method-chaining

I am trying to figure out how to get this to work correctly:

```
class A {
    john(): B {
        return this; // <-- ERROR HERE
    }
}

class B extends A {
    joe(): B {
        return this;
    }
}
```

So I can do method chaining:

```
let instance = new B();
instance.john().joe();
```

Of course, TypeScript complains that `this` doesn't match B's type.

Comment: You don't need "parent this" since a B is also a A.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use the `this` keyword as the return type of methods that return `this`:

```
class A {
    john(): this {
        return this;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    joe(): this {
        return this;
    }
}

let instance = new B();
instance.john().joe();
```

You can also omit the return types. TypeScript will infer the return types as `this` because the methods return `this`:

```
class A {
    john() {
        return this;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    joe() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

This feature is called [Polymorphic `this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) and was [introduced](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.7.html#this-typing) in TypeScript 1.7. See the [GitHub PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910) for details.